# Using a variable in a multilinestring in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandasql

I'm trying to put an sql query in a string using pandasql pulled from AI's GPT-3.
the query is  **SELECT * FROM netflix WHERE release_year = 2020 AND type = 'Movie' AND listed_in LIKE '%Horror%**
What i have at the moment is this:

```
sql_query = "* FROM netflix WHERE release_year = 2020 AND type = 'Movie' AND listed_in LIKE '%Horror%"
q = "SELECT" + sql_query

print(pysqldf(q))
```

however it keeps throwing up the error *unrecognized token: "'%Horror%"*

I'm not really sure how to get around this?

Comment: You missed a quote `'` for the `'%Horror%'` ?

Comment: look at the quote  `'` before '%Horror%.

Comment: Sorry that would be a typo I copied and pasted in a rush

Answer (score 1):

You have several typo errors in your query string.  Here is a working query:

```py
sql_query = "* FROM netflix WHERE release_year = 2020 AND type = 'Movie' AND listed_in LIKE '%Horror%'"
q = "SELECT " + sql_query
```

You need a space after the `SELECT` keyword, and also what follows `LIKE` must be in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

your are missing `'` in the end of `%Horror%`

```
sql_query = "* FROM netflix WHERE release_year = 2020 AND type = 'Movie' AND listed_in LIKE '%Horror%'"
q = "SELECT" + sql_query

print(pysqldf(q))
```